# How to detect significant Peaks?

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a table with **coordinate-points (X,Y-shown as a Chart-Series)**. Now I checked out how to detect peaks.
For each **Point (P)** I have to check whether **(P.Y > P-1.Y && P.Y > P+1.Y)**. If it is, it must be a Peak.

But what if I want to get only the really significant peaks for the entire graph? My guess is, I would neet some kind of **threshold**. What could this threshold be or how should I change the condition for peaks?

Comment: I think the first thing you'd need to do is define what are considered to be significant peaks. A peak which is surrounded by some really large troughs may be considered to be significant, or a peak which is in the largest 20% of Y values may be considered significant. It all depends upon your definition.

Comment: This is a question about algorithms, if not mathematics (signal processing comes to mind). It has nothing to do with c#, .net. Eg, what do you mean by significant peak?  Would a high-pass filter implementation suffice?

Comment: WikiPedia is a good source for algorithms  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenChrom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing coming to my mind:

```
public bool IsPeak(Point prev, Point aPoint, Point next, float threshold)
    {
        return aPoint.Y - prev.Y > threshold && aPoint.Y - next.Y;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The threshold is the distance away from each point that you check to see if it is lower than the current point.  In your first case you check one point away so we could say that your threshold is 1.